# Multi Selectable and Custom Item Grid SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mobile, view

Hello everyone I tried to create a selectable item in SwiftUI like the image bellow, but I don't know how to do that when i touch on each item change the color and color font, and after that add this item to a new state, that would be a list,this is my code and i'm using a library in order to organice the items.

[image: Grid Items]

This is my item's code

```
import SwiftUI

struct SportItem: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    var sport: Sport
    var backgroundColor: Color = Color(red: 103, green: 80, blue: 164)
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text(sport.emoji)
            Text("  "+sport.name)
                .bold()
        }.font(.system(size: 14))
        .padding(8)
//        .background(backgroundColor)
        .background(Color(red: 0.403921568627451, green: 0.3137254901960784, blue: 0.6431372549019608))
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .cornerRadius(15)
        .shadow(color: Color.black, radius: 3)
        
    }
}

struct SportItem_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var modelData = ModelData()
    
    static var previews: some View {
        SportItem(sport: modelData.sports[6])
            .environmentObject(modelData)
        
    }
}
```

I try to create a grid, the goal is this file to create the state variable a can choose sport I wanted

```
import SwiftUI
import WrappingStack

struct SelectSport: View {
    
    var event: Event
    
    @State private var eventForm = Event(id: Int(), name: "", place: "", description: "",date: Date(), beginTime: 1, endTime: 2, img: "", sports: Set<Sport>())
    
    
    
    @State var selectedSports: Set<Sport> =  Set<Sport>()
    
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    var sportsList: [Sport] { modelData.sports }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Which sports do you want to include?")
            Text(event.name)
            WrappingHStack {
                ForEach(sportsList){
                    sport in
                    SportItem(sport: sport)
                        .padding(4)
                }
            }
            
        }
        .navigationTitle("Select Sports")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                NavigationLink(destination:DatePickerEvent(event: Event(id: 1, name: "", place: "", description: "", date: Date(), beginTime: 1, endTime: 1, img: "", sports: Set<Sport>() ))){
                Text("Next")
            }
        )
    }
}

struct SelectSport_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SelectSport(event: Event(id: 1, name: "", place: "", description: "",date: Date(), beginTime: 1, endTime: 2, img: "", sports: Set<Sport>()))
            .environmentObject(ModelData())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add an `isSelected` property to `SportItem`, and change how you draw the item depending on `isSelected`. For example:

```
struct SportItem: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    var sport: Sport
    var isSelected: Bool // <— ADD THIS

    // CHANGE THIS
    var backgroundColor: Color {
        if isSelected { return Color.red }
        else { return Color(red: 0.403921568627451, green: 0.3137254901960784, blue: 0.6431372549019608) }
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text(sport.emoji)
            Text("  "+sport.name)
                .bold()
        }.font(.system(size: 14))
        .padding(8)
        .background(backgroundColor) // <- CHANGE THIS
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .cornerRadius(15)
        .shadow(color: Color.black, radius: 3)
        
    }
}
```

Then, in `SelectSport`, make two changes:

1. Pass the `isSelected` property to `SportItem`. The value to pass depends on whether `selectedSports` contains `sport`.
2. Add an `.onTapGesture` modifier after `SportItem` that toggles whether `selectedSports` contains `sport`.

For example:

```
SportItem(sport: sport, isSelected: selectedSports.contains(sport))
    .onTapGesture {
        selectedSports.formSymmetricDifference([sport])
    }
    .padding(4)
```